# Setting an object property using a method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I am creating a class in MATLAB and while I have little experience with objects, I am almost positive I should be able to set a class property using a class method.  Is this possible in MATLAB?

```
classdef foo
    properties
        changeMe 
    end

    methods
        function go()
          (THIS OBJECT).changeMe = 1;
        end
    end
end

f = foo;
f.go;


t.changeMe;
ans = 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Note that if you create a value object, the method has to return the object in order to change a property (since value objects are passed by value). If you create a handle object (`classdef foo<handle`), the object is passed by reference.

```
classdef foo
    properties
        changeMe = 0;
    end

    methods
        function self = go(self)
          self.changeMe = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

---

As mentioned above, the call of a setting method on a value object returns the changed object. If you want to change an object, you have to copy the output back to the object.

```
f = foo;
f.changeMe
ans =
   0

f = f.go;

f.changeMe
ans =
   1
```